# Issue with MVC route conflicts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a multilingual MVC application which among other things has some simple "CMS" pages which are handled by a page controller. The route which I've defined is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Page",
    "Page/{name}",
    new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", name = "" }
);
```

Also I have a method defined in a "base controller" which is used to change the language of the current page.

```
public ActionResult ChangeCulture(Culture lang, string returnUrl)
{
    if (returnUrl.Length >= 3)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl.Substring(3);
    }

    return Redirect("/" + lang.ToString() + returnUrl);
}
```

For example, for the "About Us" page in English, the Spanish version is available via the following URL:
http://localhost/en/Page/ChangeCulture?lang=2&returnUrl=/es/Page/AboutUs

The problem is that this URL maps to the route that I've defined for the CMS pages which obviously does not exist. Is there a way I can ignore the URL "Page/ChangeCulture" so it maps to the correct method i.e. the one defined in the "base controller"?

Thanks,

Jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting [route constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) on name parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Page",
                "Page/{name}",
                new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", name = "" },
                new { name = new PageNameConstraint() }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should re-architect your URLs. Why is the spanish version of the About Us page be served in different URLs? In your example:

1. http://localhost/en/Page/ChangeCulture?lang=2&returnUrl=/es/Page/AboutUs
2. http://localhost/es/Page/AboutUs

Make every page work in every language with a consistent URL (in this example, the second one).
Your routing would then look like:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    "Page",
    "{lang}/Page/{name}",
    new { controller = "Page", lang = "en", action = "Index", name = "" }
);
```

and you can even call `RedirectToaction` instead of `Redirect` and use more robust form of constructing the URL. e.g. :

```
RedirectToAction("Index", new { page = "AboutUS", lang = "es" } );
```

Comment: The URL I added was just to indicate that there is a confusion for the  method "ChangeCulture" and a page of the same name. My links for the "About Us" pages are: http://localhost/es/Page/AboutUs (Spanish) and http://localhost/en/Page/AboutUs (English).